# Force image inside flexbox container to fill/cover 100%

Tags: html, image, flexbox, fill, aspect-ratio

I'm relatively new to coding and need your help.

**Here's the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdMjZy**

```
 <div class="flex-item w50 fill">
    <div class="flex-inner portfolio">
       <a href="">
          <img src="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**What I need: Images should fill/cover the flex-item container. They should be centered and stay in aspect-ratio.**

You can see that the images with the chairs are not 100% height.

I tried to use imagefill.js but that resulted in 0px height flex-items.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can set `object-fit: cover` for your `img`. Your `a` element must be a flexbox to make `object-fit` work.
**Note that:** I just add  `resize: both;` to  `.flex-inner` for demo only. You can resize the  `.flex-inner` to see effect

```css
.flex-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-inner a {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #123;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-inner">
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x200" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

All the methods mentioned here and everywhere else didn't work efficiently . I have 52 Flex boxes , aligned 13 x 4 , and inside each box , there is an image with 6 x 6 cm dimensions .
What worked for me is targeting the `<a>` element :

```
.container nav ul li a {

    display: block;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: 0 0;
    margin: .2em;
}
```